# Capturing Error Events

Tags: vb.net

I was creating some complex applications in Visual Basic .NET 2008 and since they are in the testing phase right now, people manage to find an error or two every so often that causes the program to crash.  The problem is that there is a tracking piece to it that logs who is currently using the programs.  When a user logs in, it logs that they are currently logged in, and if the form close event is fired, the log is deleted to show that they have closed it.

Now my problem comes whenever the form crashes from an error since it won't trigger the close event and therefore makes the log become inaccurate.  My question is if it is possible to capture any error that the form would have in the form of an event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try double-clicking on "My Project" in the Solution Explorer.

On the "Application" tab, toward the bottom is a "View Application Events" button.  Click it.

You should see an "ApplicationEvents" file.  Select the `UnhandledException` event.

It should look like this:

```
Namespace My

  ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
  ' 
  ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
  ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
  ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
  ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
  ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
  Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
      // log your exception here.
    End Sub
  End Class

End Namespace
```

Note: this event will not fire [while a debugger is attached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.unhandledexception.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for an excellent response and example.  This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code around [Try...Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) blocks to catch exceptions thrown.

Example :

```
Public Sub testProgram()

        Try

            'the code goes here

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

        End Try

End Sub
```

Actually exception handling should be done at development stage. Doing this now will be a tedious task.

Comment: A global try-catch won't work in a Release version of your application. You'll want to handle ThreadException. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7482/User-Friendly-Exception-Handling

Comment: Anyway in Debug mode you certainly don't want a global try-catch, you want it to crash on the specific line which is in error. So the exception handling for unhandled exception should only be done in Release.